# Django Rest Framework link logged user to app model

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework

When I add a new Article, I have a dropdown with a list of all registered users. I want to link the current user to the new Article.
models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings

User = settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL


class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='Article', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

serializers.py

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Article


class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'user']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the solution:

```
class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        read_only=True, default=serializers.CurrentUserDefault())

    class Meta:
        model = Article
        fields = ['id', 'title', 'user']

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        kwargs["user"] = self.fields["user"].get_default()
        return super().save(**kwargs)
```